# Insert script returned via JSON into <head> before another dependent script loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wordpress, head

I've got a weird script firing problem that I don't know how to solve. I've searched all over the place, but it's tough to know what to call to Google without getting irrelevant results. Here's the scenario:

I'm connecting and Wordpress site and a Magento site. In order to pull data from Magento, our Magento devs set up some JSON calls I can make. I need to make those calls and use the data it returns before I execute some scripts on my side. That JSON call contains a script that includes a several `<script>` tags that set config variables to be used in several other dependent scripts. I've got my scripts enqueued in Wordpress to fire in the order that I need them in the head:

1. My script with JSON call
2. Dependent script
3. Dependent script
4. Dependent script
5. Dependent script

**My first question:** Can my script file write this string of text that's being returned in JSON, containing `<script>` tags, into the `<head>` of the document and have that text be referenced by those dependent scripts? (In the code below, I'm using document.write. I'm sure that's probably bad practice)

**My second question:** Even if I'm able to do that, is it going to be irrelevant because the data from JSON will not be available yet when the other scripts are loaded? Do I need to set up some kind of dependency that only loads those other scripts once my JSON returns the config variables?

My JSON calls in my external script, if that helps:

```
var cartrequest = JSON.stringify({"full_action_name":"cms_index_index","blocks":{"tag":"cart_sidebar"}});

var searchrequest = JSON.stringify({"full_action_name":"cms_index_index","blocks":{"tag":"search-configuration"}});

$.when( $.ajax( "/store/_diehard/load/json",{"data":{"json":cartrequest}} ), $.ajax( "/store/_diehard/load/json",{"data":{"json":searchrequest}} ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
    $("#shopping-cart").html( resp.blocks.tag );
    var headInsert = a2[0].blocks.tag;
    document.write(headInsert);
});
```

Comment: Suggestion: Use `jQuery promises` so that your dependant scripts only fire when the data has actually been returned.

Comment: Also, don't use `document.write`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah, I definitely figured that wasn't the right way to go. What would be a better alternative, though?